# List View Threshold Issue for List

Tags: 2010, list-view, error, list-view-threshold

I am getting the Error when clicking on "Add new item" for a list.(list has crossed 5000).

So i increased the LVT, indexed the columns and filtered the list using the index column to bring the list to less than 5000 records.

However, when I bring down the LVT the error still  persists.

Do i need to filter all the views present for the list? Kindly help.

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list-view-threshold  you might find some useful information from other user's questions

Answer (score 0):

yes, you are right. Filtering with indexed columns is one way to do it.
You have to optimize each view if you want to continue to use it. LVT actually says it, it's the List View Threshold.

A list can have much more items, but a view MUST NOT have to use more than the threshold on items. And here, it is not sufficient to set the item limit to less than the LVT, you also need to take care, that e.g. for sorting and filtering, you use only *indexed columns*.

E.g. as long as you only sort by ID (which is always indexed) and have no filter, grouping or any other non defaults configured and you have set item limit (= paging) to less than LVT, your view should work, even if the list contains much more than 5,000 items.

Please find here a relevant presentation on this topic:

[https://www.slideshare.net/SteveStewart5/working-with-large-lists-in-sharepoint-2013-why-you-need-to-pay-attention-to-thresholds-and-metadata](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

--> Starting with slide 23, it gives some tips how to set up views in lists with items > LVT.

Below is a link with some Microsoft information on this topic:

[https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Comment: Reading your question again, you are saying, you get an error message, when creating list items. Is this error message starting with: "This view cannot be displayed because it exceeds the list view threshold ..."?
In this case, the error message is not related to the creation of the item, but just related to the view. Your item is created in this list, the currently selected view is just not able to show any items after the new item got created.

Comment: If it appears directly after clicking "new item", this is not normal, please provide some more information to e.g. reproduce the issue: exact error message, version of SharePoint, browser, type of list, number of items LVT  ...